# Match group only if it's different than other matching group

Tags: python, regex

I want to match every substring that begins with `w` and ends `d` with regex.

For example for input `worldworld` it should return
`('worldworld', 'world', 'world')`. (note: there are two `world` but they are different because they are at different position in the string)

For this purpose I ended with this program [with following regex](https://regex101.com/r/P9rUqU/2/):

```
import re

s = '''worldworld'''

for g in re.finditer(r'(?=(w.*d))(?=(w.*?d))', s):
    print(g.start(1), g.end(1), g[1])
    print(g.start(2), g.end(2), g[2])
    print('-' * 40)
```

This prints:

```
0 10 worldworld
0 5 world
----------------------------------------
5 10 world
5 10 world
----------------------------------------
```

It finds all substrings, but some are duplicates also (notice the starting and ending position of the group).

I can filter the groups afterwards with group's starting and ending position, but I'm wondering if it can be done with change to my regex, to only return unique groups.

Can I change this regex to only match group that is different from other? If yes how? I'm open to suggestions how to solve this problem.

Comment: In your desired output you have `('worldworld', 'world', 'world')`, but then you state you do not want duplicates. Which one is it?

Comment: @UnbearableLightness Duplicates in sense of position of substring.

Comment: The test string `wdddd` shows another problem (it will never match the `wdd` or `wddd` prefixes).  Use a pair of nested `string.find()` loops instead?

Comment: You can't just rely on `.*` and `.*?`. What about `worldworldworld`? I suppose you expect all the combinations, right? I don't think this best done with regex.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed Yes, all the combinations of substrings. I'm thinking about this problem but yeah, maybe regex isn't suited for it.

Comment: @TimPeters Yes, you have right. Maybe regex isn't suited for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe this can be done with a single regexp.  But it's straightforward with a nested loop:

```
import re
test = "wddddd"
# need to compile the tail regexp to get a version of
# `finditer` that allows specifying a start index
tailre = re.compile("(d)")
for wg in re.finditer("(w)", test):
    start = wg.start(1)
    for dg in tailre.finditer(test, wg.end(1)):
        end = dg.end(1)
        print(test[start : end], "at", (start, end))
```

That displays:

```
wd at (0, 2)
wdd at (0, 3)
wddd at (0, 4)
wdddd at (0, 5)
wddddd at (0, 6)
```

With

```
test = "worldworldworld"
```

instead:

```
world at (0, 5)
worldworld at (0, 10)
worldworldworld at (0, 15)
world at (5, 10)
worldworld at (5, 15)
world at (10, 15)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yeah, the duplicate links shown me that it's not possible with single regex. I didn't know that you can put `start` to regular expression object, TIL :)

Comment: Oh yes - many regexp (and string) methods allow specifying slice indices.  That can make some seemingly intractable tasks easy and efficient (of course under the covers no slice is extracted - the indices just the tell methods where to start (and stop) looking).

Answer (score 1):

One option would be, with the lazy second group, to positive lookahead for `.*d` (greedy) afterwards to ensure that *if* the lazy second group matches, it's not the same as the greedy first group:

```
(?=(w.*d))(?:(?=(w.*?d)(?=.*d)))?
```

https://regex101.com/r/UI9ds7/2

Comment: Which doesn't work for `worldworldworld` as explained in the comments above.